# The findAll() of TYPO3 extbase repository in Command Controller returns empty object

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I wanna use the repository in the Command Controller to execute a procedure from time to time. I have the repository inject  in the Action Controller and Command Controller, there are exist objects but in the Command Controller returns empty.

I am using the next code in two places, Action and Command.

```
/**
 * postRepository
 *
 * @var \VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Repository\PostRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $postRepository = null;

....
....
$posts = $this->postRepository->findAll();
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\DebugUtility::debug($posts, 'posts');
```

And the moment of Debug. In Action Controller I get

> TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResultprototypeobject (5 items)

And in Command Controller

> TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QueryResultprototypeobject (empty)

What is the correct way for use repositories in Command Controller or how could I get the objects in this?

I am using TYPO3 7.6, PHP 5.6 and APC cache in Install Tools and configure it in the Server, Centos 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `StoragePage` is not set in your Command Controller.  You may try `$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE)` in your `PostRepository`, or `module.tx_myext.persistence.storagePid = {$storagePid}` in your extension TS.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was resolved with `$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE)`.